# ASP .NET Cannot access a disposed stream

Tags: c#, closedxml

I'm trying to generate an excel file and then pass it to http response:

```
    [HttpPost("downloadCodesFile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadExcelFile(GetSeriesExcelSheetRequest request)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
        {

            var codes = await _dataContext.Codes.Where(c => c.IsActive && c.SeriesNumber == request.SeriesNumber)
           .Select(entry => entry.CodeName).ToListAsync();

            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

            // Set cell values
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var code in codes)
            {
                worksheet.Cell($"A{i}").Value = code;
                i++;
            }

            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        };
    }
```

The file got generated once when I testes but then I keep getting the following error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StreamCopyOperationInternal.CopyToAsync(Stream source, Stream destination, Nullable`1 count, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Internal.FileResultHelper.WriteFileAsync(HttpContext context, Stream fileStream, RangeItemHeaderValue range, Int64 rangeLength)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileResultExecutorBase.WriteFileAsync(HttpContext context, Stream fileStream, RangeItemHeaderValue range, Int64 rangeLength)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileStreamResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, FileStreamResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Been trying to figure out by adding stream to using block, without success

Comment: Could you please provide more lines of the exception stack trace?

Comment: sure, updated..

Comment: with the stacktrace added, that looks like the FileStreamResult being invoked, which *suggests* that the held payload stream held has been disposed; are you sure your actual code doesn't have a `using` on the `stream` declaration, i.e. `using var stream = ...` ?

Comment: Could it be that the workbook.SaveAs disposes the stream?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek that's what I was trying to look into; the XLWorkbook I can find: SaveAs takes a *path* (and is COM interop for VSTO, which IIRC isn't even supported in web applications); maybe Nina can be specific about what that XLWorkbook is, so we can find the API declaration

Comment: Yup, I think that's closedXML library. The API doc does not describe the behavior at all, unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like `ClosedXml`, in `SaveAs`, updates `_originalStream`; I would say that this is a bug (I guess it is so that `Save()` works, but... weird), but: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook.cs#L575 - this suggests two workarounds: 1) don't dispose the workbook, 2) copy the buffer out *before* disposing the workbook (/cc @ZdeněkJelínek)

Comment: Can you provide some more info on how to implement it?

Comment: @NinaMarszałek What version of ClosedXML exactly are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like there's a glitch in `XLWorkbook` whereby `SaveAs` keeps hold of the supplied stream, and it *looks* like `Dispose()` is then hooked by Fody to dispose that.

This presents two options:

1. remove the `using` in `using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())` - so you just have `var workbook = new XLWorkbook();` - this is ... ugly and unsatisfying, because we *don't know* what else this is not disposing
2. copy the data out, assuming that what we give to `SaveAs` is going to be burned

Consider:

```cs
Stream stream;
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
    // ... write the content etc

    using var tmp = new MemoryStream(); // will be burned with workbook
    workbook.SaveAs(tmp);
    stream = new MemoryStream(tmp.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)tmp.Length);
};
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

This reuses the underlying buffer (no additional copies), but in a second `MemoryStream` instance that is not disposed.

Comment: Just to add, there is already an issue reported with ClosedXML for this: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/912

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek added a xref there, thanks